# Find the limit of the function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

Let we have the following function
$$F(x)=\frac{x^x-x}{\ln(x)-x+1}$$
Find $$\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^x-x}{\ln(x)-x+1}$$

Comment: Notice that both the top and bottom of the fraction approach $0$ as $x \to 1$. What can be done about limits that tend to $\frac{0}{0}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use l'Hopital's rule since the limit of the top and bottom is 0. Call the numerator f(x) and the denominator g(x). Find f'(x) and g'(x) then find lim f'(x)/g'(x). If the limit still results in an indeterminate form you can repeat the process. Lim f(x)/g(x)= lim f'(x)/g'(x)

Answer (score 4):

Hint: given the form of the limit, you can use L'Hopital's rule twice.

Answer (score 2):

In a neighbourhood of the origin,
$$ (1+z)^{(1+z)}=\exp\left((1+z)\log(1+z)\right)=\exp\left((1+z)(z-\frac{z^2}{2}+O(z^3))\right)\\=\exp\left(z+\frac{z^2}{2}+O(z^3)\right)=1+z+z^2+O(z^3)$$
so the given limit equals:
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(1+z+z^2)-(1+z)}{\left(z-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)-z}=\color{red}{-2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\large L=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^x-x}{\ln(x)-x+1}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^x(1+\log x)-1}{1/x-1}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{x+1}+x^{x+1}\log x-x}{1-x}=\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{x^{x+1}+x^{x+1}\log x-x}{1-x}\\\large =\lim_{x \to 1}-(x^x(1+x+x\ln x)+x^x(1+\ln x)(1+x\ln x)-1)=-2$$

---

### Notes:

- $$y=x^x\implies \ln y=x\ln x\implies y'/y=1+\ln x\implies y'=y(1+\ln x)$$
- $$y=x^{x+1}=x^x.x\implies y'=x^x(1+\ln x).x+x^x=x^x(1+x+x\ln x)$$
- $$y=x^{x+1}\ln x\implies y'=x^x(1+x+x\ln x).\ln x+x^{x+1}/x=x^x(1+\ln x)(1+x\ln x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $u=x^x$ we have $$\log u(x)=x\log x$$

$$ \frac 1 {u(x)} u'(x)=1+\log x$$

$$u'(x)={u(x)}(1+\log x)$$

Now, By L'Hospital Rule,

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^x-x}{\log x-x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{u(x)(1+\log x)-1}{\frac 1 x -1}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{u'(x)(1+\log x)+u(x)(1+\frac 1 x)}{\frac {-1}{x^2}}=\frac{u'(1)+2}{-1}=\frac {1+2}{-1}=-3$$

Comment: may be some calculation mistake... kindly make a close observe..